# Create dummy data with LETTERS[1:3] recycled as a new feature on a df of varying length

Tags: r

I'm finding this surprisingly challenging.

Example:

```
library(tidyverse)
diamonds %>% mutate(DummyCategory = LETTERS[1:3])
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `DummyCategory`.
x Input `DummyCategory` can't be recycled to size 53940.
ℹ Input `DummyCategory` is `LETTERS[1:3]`.
ℹ Input `DummyCategory` must be size 53940 or 1, not 3.
```

Tried base R

```
 my_diamonds <- diamonds
> my_diamonds$DummyCategory <- LETTERS[1:3]
Error: Assigned data `LETTERS[1:3]` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 53940 rows.
x Assigned data has 3 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
```

I would like a new column DummyCategory To be the values A, B, C, recycled to however long the dataframe is and it doesn't matter if A,B,C are not divisible by nrow of end up with differing frequencies, I'd just like to recycle till all rows in diamonds have a new DummyCategory. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As provided in the documentation for `mutate()`, the value can be:

> A vector of length 1, which will be recycled to the correct length.
>
> A vector the same length as the current group (or the whole data frame
> if ungrouped).
>
> NULL, to remove the column.
>
> A data frame or tibble, to create multiple columns in the output.

Therefore, it won't recycle the vector to the length of the df. You can, however, do:

```
diamonds %>% 
 mutate(DummyCategory = rep(LETTERS[1:3], length.out = n()))

   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z DummyCategory
   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        
 1 0.23  Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43 A            
 2 0.21  Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31 B            
 3 0.23  Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31 C            
 4 0.290 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63 A            
 5 0.31  Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75 B            
 6 0.24  Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48 C            
 7 0.24  Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47 A            
 8 0.26  Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53 B            
 9 0.22  Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49 C            
10 0.23  Very Good H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39 A
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is next:

```
#Code
diamonds$DummyCategory <- rep(LETTERS[1:3],dim(diamonds)[1]/length(LETTERS[1:3]))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 53,940 x 11
   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z DummyCategory
   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        
 1 0.23  Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43 A            
 2 0.21  Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31 B            
 3 0.23  Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31 C            
 4 0.290 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63 A            
 5 0.31  Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75 B            
 6 0.24  Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48 C            
 7 0.24  Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47 A            
 8 0.26  Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53 B            
 9 0.22  Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49 C            
10 0.23  Very Good H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39 A            
# ... with 53,930 more rows
```

The other option is using `data.frame()` with the data and vector:

```
diamonds <- data.frame(diamonds,DummyCategory=LETTERS[1:3])
```

Output:

```
   carat       cut color clarity depth table price    x    y    z DummyCategory
1   0.23     Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326 3.95 3.98 2.43             A
2   0.21   Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326 3.89 3.84 2.31             B
3   0.23      Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327 4.05 4.07 2.31             C
4   0.29   Premium     I     VS2  62.4    58   334 4.20 4.23 2.63             A
5   0.31      Good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335 4.34 4.35 2.75             B
6   0.24 Very Good     J    VVS2  62.8    57   336 3.94 3.96 2.48             C
7   0.24 Very Good     I    VVS1  62.3    57   336 3.95 3.98 2.47             A
8   0.26 Very Good     H     SI1  61.9    55   337 4.07 4.11 2.53             B
9   0.22      Fair     E     VS2  65.1    61   337 3.87 3.78 2.49             C
10  0.23 Very Good     H     VS1  59.4    61   338 4.00 4.05 2.39             A
```